# Phonegap: Would like to set volume of speakers individually (change balance)

Tags: audio, cordova

In Android, one can set the volume of the left and right speakers separately by using the `android.media.MediaPlayer.setVolume` method which takes two arguments: one `float` for the left speaker and another for the right speaker.

In Phonegap/Cordova, there is a [`media.setVolume`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.setVolume) method which only takes a single argument to set the volume of the media.

How can I the volume of each speaker individually in Phonegap?

Comment: You would need to find or build a plugin for this. It maybe, easy enough to copy the default media plugin and make a modified version that accepts both params.